# Search Toolbar with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is a newbie question about Angular 1.4.

**My Main Question**

I have the following search view:

```
'use strict';

var module = angular.module('myapp.search', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

module.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    });
});

module.factory('Search', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('http://www.myapp.com/api/search', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: false
        }
    });
});

module.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, Search) {
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.query = '';   
    $scope.doSearch = function (query) {
        Search.query({q: query}).$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.results = result.results;
        });
    };
});
```

And the partial HTML (search.html):

```
#search.html

<input placeholder="search" ng-model="query" />
<button ng-click="doSearch(query)" />
<h1>Results</h1>
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="result in results">{{ result }}</li>
</ol>
...
```

This works perfectly, the problem is when I want to put the search input in a toolbar (defined in index.html):

```
#index.html

<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <input placeholder="search" ng-model="query" />
    <button ng-click="doSearch(query)">
  </div>
  ...
```

In this case, by pushing the search button the query is executed in the back-end but the results are not updated in $scope. what's wrong? I've tried calling $scope.$apply() with no luck. I'm lost with this.

**Bonus Question**

Given that the search functionality is in the toolbar (always visible) users can execute queries in any place of the website. How can I redirect the response to `http://www.myapp.com/search`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its should work as code looks good..

Comment: You didn't close your button tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct instances of SearchCtrl, each with its own distinct scope: one in the navbar (dur to `ng-controller="SearchCtrl"`), and one in the main view (due to `controller: 'SearchCtrl'`).

So the search in the navbar modifies the scope of the navbar controller, and the scope of the main view doesn't know anything about it.

If you want to got to the search main view when something is searched in the navbar, simply use

```
$location.url('/search?query=' + theEncodedQueryTypedByTheUser);
```

And in the search route's resolve function, or in its controller, get the route param named `query`, send the HTTP request, and update the scope with the results.

Comment: You've saved me a lot of time. Thank you!